# Шаблон главной страницы магазина

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Для магазина woocommerce по умолчанию создаются такие страницы:
Витрина, корзина, мой аккаунт, оформление заказа.
Я создал ещё одну страницу для главной страницы магазина под названием - Главная страница.
Также я создал новый шаблон витрины в php-файле, в котором в начале определено как Template name: Витрина
Меня интересует, если я делаю такую последовательность действий:
1) в админ-панели "Настройки - Чтение. В опции "На главной странице отображать" выбираю "Статическую страницу (выберите ниже)" выбираю - Витрина.
2) в админ-панели "Страницы" выбираю страницу "Витрина" и в боковом меню назначаю ей вышеприведённый php-шаблон под названием "Витрина".
3) в админ-панели "WooCommerce"->"Настройки"->"Товары"->"Отображение" - "Страница Магазина" выбираю "Витрина"
в результате на главной странице выдаёт ошибку, и выводит шаблон archive-product.php
А если в 3м шаге в отображении выбрать не "Витрина" а выбрать "Главная страница", тогда новый php-шаблон "Витрина" нормально подключается к главной странице.
Объясните пожалуйста, почему выдаёт ошибку?
т.е. для двух страниц: Витрина и Главная страница назначен один и тот же новый php-шаблон "Витрина"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройке "WooCommerce"->"Настройки"->"Товары"->"Отображение" - "Страница Магазина" устанавливается, какая страница будет выводиться WooCommerce как страница магазина. Это особая страница, генерируемая WooCommerce по шаблону `archive-product.php`.

Ваши шаги 1-2 правильные, а шаг 3 - лишний.

Comment: >Это особая страница

Comment: А как понять особая страница? т.е. шаги 1-2 это вообще не относится к настройке витрины магазина?

Comment: Нет. Шаг 1 - вообще просто настройка главной. Шаг 2 - настройка любой страницы, на которой хочется вывести информацию из магазина в своем формате. Главной страницей магазина можно считать все, что угодно, а стандартную страницу магазина никак не оформлять и даже спрятать.